# When does ffmpeg terminate?

Tags: java, video, encoding, ffmpeg, xuggle

I am running `ffmpeg.exe` through a Java code to encode a video file. How will my program come to know when ffmpeg terminated (i.e. video file is encoded)?

Here is the code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -ac 2 -i audio.wav -i video.flv -sameq out.flv");
```

Comment: You will discover that is a very fragile way to construct a `Process` when it encounters a path or file name containing a space.  As general tips. 1) Use the methods that accept an array of arguments. 2) Use a `ProcessBuilder` for 1.5+ code, which then makes it slightly simpler to 3) Implement all the suggestions of  [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)  BTW - why use ffmpeg rather than jffmpeg?

Comment: What does this have to do with Xuggle?  To my knowledge, ffmpeg & Xuggle are entirely separate projects.

Comment: I was unaware about jffmpeg.Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `waitFor()` method of [`java.lang.Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg...");
int exitValue = p.waitFor()
```

With this, the current thread waits until the `Process p` has terminated.

EDIT:

You can try to see the output from ffmpeg:

```
class StreamDump implements Runnable {

    private InputStream stream;

    StreamDump(InputStream input) {
        this.stream = input;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int c;
            while ((c = stream.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.write(c);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg.exe...");
new Thread(new StreamDump(p.getErrorStream()), "error stream").start();
new Thread(new StreamDump(p.getInputStream()), "output stream").start();
try {
    p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Exit value: " + p.exitValue());
```

Comment: No the current thread and the parent thread both go to the wait state.And the video encoding also pauses.

Comment: You miss parenthesis, it should be `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg..."); `

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around,if the file out.flv is tried to rename while it is being encoded it wouldn't allow,It can only be renamed after the encoding is over :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -ac 2 -i audio.wav -i video.flv -sameq out.flv");

File tempFile=new File("out.flv");
File renamedFile=new File("renamed.flv");
while(!tempFile.renameTo(renamedFile)); //try re-naming the file which is being encoded by ffmpeg

System.out.println("Encoding done");
```